# Dirty price of US T bill

Tags: accrued-interest

I need to calculate the dirty price of a US T bond given the below details:

Assume the coupons on a U.S. Treasury bond are paid on January 1st and July 1st. 
The bond has a par of $1,000 and pays a semiannual coupon of 4.0% with a yield of 6.0%. 
The bond has a settlement date on April 4th, 2011. The bond matures on January 1st, 2016 
such that there are ten (10) remaining semi-annual coupon payments. What is the dirty 
price (a.k.a., full price) of the bond?

My initial thought was to calculate the PV of the bond and add accrued interest/

**I've been told this is incorrect and I need to compound the present value forward at the yield for for the 93 days between the last coupon Jan 1 and the settlement date April 4.**

```
$914.6980*(1.03)^(93/181) = $928.696 is the full (dirty) price as of settlement date
```

**My question:**
Why can't I just add accrued interest the the PV as of Jan 1 ? Is the PV as of Jan 1 not the "clean" price ?

**This is what I tried**

```
Use calculator to get PV:

Number of periods = 10
Yield = 6/2
Payment = 20
Future Vale = 1000
Resulting in a PV of $914.698

And then calculate the accrued interest from April 4 to July 1 using the ACT/ACT day     count such that:
AI = $20*(93/181)=$10.276

Resulting in the dirty price 914.698 + 10.276= 924.974
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @olaker Money.SE isn't going to want this question. They deal with *personal* finance, like retirement planning and taxation.

Comment: @chrisaycock: my fault. Can it be migrated back and closed as a basic one?

Comment: @olaker They'll probably just close it on their end.